# Use Facebook API from personal website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

A client has asked me to create an XML document with all the info I can gather from his personal Facebook account. The document should include all info about his account, plus all the info his account can see in his friends' accounts (name, likes, comments, photos etc). Is this possible to achieve on **a private server** through some API? Do I have to make a Facebook app or can I get all this information if he's merely logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all his publicly viewable information via the graph api:
graph.facebook.com/ID (Where id is his facebook ID) will give you a JSON file with data on gender, name etc. Photos and comments are different as you need the ID of the photo, which I'm not sure how you could pull off the public api.

To access anything that is not set to public you will need to create an app and he will need to add the app and allow it access to his information.

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ for more info, pretty much guides you through anything you would want to do.

Comment: So just being logged in is not enough to retrieve his non-public personal info, right? And how about his friends? I was thinking that since all this info is viewable for him as a logged in person, it could also be viewable for a program.